# Python: extracting lines from a database

Tags: python

I have a file that contain IDs and I'm Trying to extract the lines the have the same IDs from another file (database). I'm trying this code, but it gives me only one line:

```
a = open ('file.txt', 'a+') # database file
b = open ('file2.txt', 'a+') # list of interest

for line1 in b:
    IPR= line1.split()[1]
    for line2 in a:
        IPR2= line2.split()[0]
        if IPR == IPR2:
            print line2
```

It seems like it's not looping, or i'm doing another mistake, could anyone help me?

Comment: Try opening the files with "r" mode (the default).

Comment: Can you show your files content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looping because you only read from your database file once, during the first iteration over `b` (after which the database file is exhausted). Have you considered reading the database into memory first as a list of lines:

```
b = open ('file2.txt', 'r') # list of interest

db = open ('file.txt', 'r').readlines() # database file

for line1 in b:
    IPR= line1.split()[1]
    for line2 in db:
        IPR2= line2.split()[0]
        if IPR == IPR2:
            print line2.rstrip()
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks. But I would like to know why did you use rstrip() instead of just printing the line?

Comment: When you read in the line, you get the newline character at the end of it too. `print` adds its own, so if you don't strip the original one each line will be printed with a blank line after it.

Comment: also it's taking forever for the code to finish, even if I reduce the number of lines

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b = open ('file2.txt', 'r') # list of interest

for line1 in b:
    IPR= line1.split()[1]
    a= open ('file.txt', 'r') # database file
    for line2 in a:
        IPR2= line2.split()[0]
        if IPR == IPR2:
            print line2
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations would be to change to the r module as this will simply read all the data in the file. as opposed to line1 and line2 just use line, as it defaults to doing the action for all lines

```
a= open ('file.txt', 'r') # database file
b= open ('file2.txt', 'r') # list of interest

for line in b:
    IPR= line.split()[1]
    for line in a:
        IPR2= line.split()[0]
        if IPR == IPR2:
            print line
```